# Div and positioning issue

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-float

I have a really hard time trying to recreate this example. Turned out the one I made isn't correctly align and I can't figure out how to loop the comment box 
the under the review score. Can anyone give me an example or explain this layout please?

Example image:

[image]

Here is what I made, I using background color to see the div box.

[image]

Here is the code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url("background.png");
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 8px;
}

.banner {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-image: url("bannerbackground.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

H1 {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

DL {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ff0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

DT {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: #cc0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

DD {
  float: left;
  width: 50%; //background: #dd0
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.overview {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
}

.everything review {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-color: grey;
}

.review p {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>TMNT - Rancid Tomatoes</TITLE>
    <META content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="movie.css">
  </HEAD>

  <BODY>
    <DIV class="banner">
      <IMG alt="Rancid Tomatoes" src="images/banner.png" align="middle">
    </DIV>
    <H1>TMNT (2007)</H1>
    <DIV class="everything" align="center">
      <DIV class="overview">
        <IMG alt="general overview" src="images/generaloverview.png">
        <DL>
          <DT>STARRING</DT>
          <DD>Mako
            <BR> Sarah Michelle Gellar</DD>
          <DT>DIRECTOR</DT>
          <DD>Kevin Munroe</DD>
          <DT>RATING</DT>
          <DD>PG</DD>
          <DT>THEATRICAL RELEASE</DT>
          <DD>Mar 23, 2007</DD>
          <DT>MOVIE SYNOPSIS</DT>
          <DD>After the defeat of their old arch nemesis, The Shredder, the Turtles have grown apart as a family.</DD>
          <DT>MPAA RATING</DT>
          <DD>PG, for animated action violence, some scary cartoon images and mild language
          </DD>
          <DT>RELEASE COMPANY</DT>
          <DD>Warner Bros.</DD>
          <DT>GENRE</DT>
          <DD>Action/Adventure, Comedies, Childrens, Martial Arts, Superheroes, Ninjas, Animated Characters</DD>
          <DT>OFFICIAL MOVIE SITE</DT>
          <DD>
            <A href="http://www.tmnt.com/">The Official TMNT Site</A>
          </DD>
        </DL>
      </DIV>
      <DIV class="review">
        <DIV>
          <IMG alt="Rotten" src="images/rottenbig.png"> 32% (88 reviews total) </DIV>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Rotten" src="images/rotten.gif">
          <Q>Ditching the cheeky, 
self-aware wink that helped to excuse the concept's inherent corniness, the 
movie attempts to look polished and 'cool,' but the been-there animation can't 
compete with the then-cutting-edge puppetry of the 1990 live-action 
movie.</Q>
        </P>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Critic" src="images/critic.gif"> Peter Debruge
          <BR> Variety </P>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Fresh" src="images/fresh.gif">
          <Q>TMNT is a fun, 
action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of 
new ones.</Q>
        </P>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Critic" src="images/critic.gif"> Todd Gilchrist
          <BR> IGN Movies </P>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Rotten" src="images/rotten.gif">
          <Q>It stinks!</Q>
        </P>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Critic" src="images/critic.gif"> Jay Sherman (unemployed)
        </P>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Rotten" src="images/rotten.gif">
          <Q>The rubber suits are 
gone and they've been redone with fancy computer technology, but that hasn't 
stopped them from becoming dull.</Q>
        </P>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Critic" src="images/critic.gif"> Joshua Tyler
          <BR> CinemaBlend.com </P>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Rotten" src="images/rotten.gif">
          <Q>The turtles themselves 
may look prettier, but are no smarter; torn irreparably from their 
countercultural roots, our superheroes on the half shell have been firmly 
co-opted by the industry their creators once sought to spoof.</Q>
        </P>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Critic" src="images/critic.gif"> Jeannette Catsoulis
          <BR> New York Times </P>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Rotten" src="images/rotten.gif">
          <Q>Impersonally animated 
and arbitrarily plotted, the story appears to have been made up as the 
filmmakers went along.</Q>
        </P>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Critic" src="images/critic.gif"> Ed Gonzalez
          <BR> Slant Magazine </P>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Fresh" src="images/fresh.gif">
          <Q>The striking use of image 
and motion allows each sequence to leave an impression. It's an accomplished 
restart to this franchise.</Q>
        </P>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Critic" src="images/critic.gif"> Mark Palermo
          <BR> Coast (Halifax, Nova Scotia) </P>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Rotten" src="images/rotten.gif">
          <Q>The script feels like it 
was computer generated. This mechanical presentation lacks the cheesy charm of 
the three live action films.</Q>
        </P>
        <P>
          <IMG alt="Critic" src="images/critic.gif"> Steve Rhodes
          <BR> Internet Reviews </P>
        <P>(1-8) of 88</P>
      </div>
    </DIV>
    <DIV>
      <A href="http://validator.w3.org/check/referer">
        <IMG alt="Valid XHTML 1.1" src="images/w3c-xhtml.png">
      </A>
      <BR>
      <A href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
        <IMG alt="Valid CSS!" src="images/w3c-css.png">
      </A>
    </DIV>
  </BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a table instead of divs. That way you can easily make the above result. For example:

```
<table id="theentiretable">
<tr>
  <td class="topleftgreen">information here</td>
  <td class="toprightblack">information here">
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="textandquotes">information here</td>
  <td class="posterimg>information here</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>any other information here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

With this way you can make the td's with any style you want and you'd have all of the above in one table making your life easier. Now you can wrap the entire table with a div to make the background and all the effects you want as well but that's up to your expectations and your needs. ;)
Alternatively, you can use two tables to make them more easy for your needs.